# what's view hierarchy and SurfaceView?

Tags: android, android-view

What is the purpose of the "view hierarchy" in Android?
as an example:

> The SurfaceView exists outside the normal view hierarchy. It actually
>   exists behind the normal window and is made visible by punching a hole
>   through the view layout  in your app. The SurfaceView can then be
>   updated independently of the rest of  your views without waiting for
>   the UI thread.

Answer (score 3):

Android's View Hierarchy is the construct (usually a [ViewGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html)) that contains all of the [View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html)s of the active screen in a tree like fashion. Its purpose, Like any other UI manager, is to delegate responsibility of actions and drawing amongst all of the views in a given application.

In your given example, it means that you have created a view that is not part of the application's parent/main ViewGroup and doesn't really have any responsibility, can't do anything useful.